# Creating Docker containers using Terraform - Error pinging Docker server

Tags: docker, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create an nginx based docker container using Terraform.
HCL:

```
terraform{
required_providers{
docker={
source="kreuzwerker/docker"
}
}
}
provider "docker" {}
resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
name ="nginx:latest"
keep_locally="false"
}
resource "docker_container" "nserver"{
image=docker_image.nginx.latest
name="nginx_server"
ports{
internal =80
external=9090
}
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

If the same error occurs in docker I would just start/ enable docker using "sudo systemctl start/enable docker" command.
But how should I deal with this error in Terraform ?

Please Help!

Comment: Well, the provider is using the daemon running on your system. How else would it know which API to use to download images and create containers? Anyway, the daemon has to be running for this to work.

Comment: @MarkoE Yeah correct! Actually I have forgot to install Docker on my instance.

Answer (score 1):

I share the solution for my case (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, Docker Desktop, Terraform).

- Check your DOCKER ENDPOINT opening a terminal and typing:

`docker context ls`

- Look there and copy your DOCKER ENDPOINT
- Open your `main.tf` and change provider line, i.e:

```
provider "docker" {
  host ="unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock"
}
```

- Save and do it again:

```
terraform init
terraform apply
```

Docs that helps me resolve this issue:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax
- https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#what-is-the-difference-between-docker-desktop-for-linux-and-docker-engine